# Copy all data from one form to another in Django admin

Tags: django, forms, django-admin

I'm having trouble making the data from a form be sent to a new form in my application.
I want to do the following: After the user clicks a button within a record, that record data be copied to another empty form.

No need to store these values permanently or for a long time. Only in the transition from one form to another with populated fields blank form.

Basically a Ctrl + C - Ctrl + V form, but without saving the record after copying ...

I've done something like working with URL parameters, but would like something cleaner.
I need to copy values including the inlines.

I thought of storing the data in the session, and then retrieve them at the target form. However, I do not know if it's the best way to implement it.
If so, how can I work with the session in Django?

This is the code I have so far in my admin.py file:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    # name of the custom button
    if '_copy_and_paste' in request.POST:
        # getting the data and storing the session
        request.session['field_1'] = obj.field_1
        request.session['field_2'] = obj.field_2

        return super(MyClassAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

I'm using the Django admin (version 1.8).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store this information in session, you can pass the request object back to your template page.

In your **settings.py** file, make sure **context_processors.request** is inside the context_processors:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...,
                'django.template.context_processors.request',  #<- make sure this line is here
                ...,
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then, in your **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def response_change(request):
    if '_copy_and_paste' in request.POST:
        return render(request, 'your_template.html')
```

In your template, to access the data stored in request:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="{% if request.POST.field1 %}{{ request.POST.field1}}{% endif %}">
```

Comment: Hello @Cheng. First, thanks for the reply!  
It turns out I do not want to redirect to a custom template, so it is not possible to include the html code.  
I want to redirect the user to the same form DjangoAdmin but empty, ie no record in the database.